# Proper way to make a request to a model, deployed via Azure ML Designer

Tags: python, azure, computer-vision, classification, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to make the POST request to the Azure ML Designer endpoint (model, I have deployed).
Here is my code:

```
import requests

scoring_uri = 'http:some-url/score'
key = 'someKey'

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
headers['Authorization'] = f'Bearer {key}'

response = requests.get('https://www.okino.ua/media/var/news/2019/12/04/Quentin_Tarantino.jpg')

input_data = "{\"data\": [" + str(response.content) + "]}"
resp = requests.post(scoring_uri, data=response.content, headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
```

And I receive and error:

```
{"error": {"code": 400, "message": "Input Data Error. Input data are inconsistent with schema.\nSchema: {'WebServiceInput0': {'columnAttributes': [{'name': 'image', 'type': 'Bytes', 'isFeature': True, 'elementType': {'typeName': 'bytes', 'isNullable': False}, 'properties': {'mime_type': 'image/png', 'image_ref': 'image_info'}}, {'name': 'id', 'type': 'Numeri\nData: b'\\xff\\xd8\\xff\\xe0\\x00\\x10JFIF\\x00\\x01\\x01\\x01\\x01,\\x01,\\x00\\x00\\xff\\xfe\\x00[Copyright Shutterstock 2019;82139424;3600;2400;1563865756;Tue, 23 Jul 2019 07:09:16 GMT;0\\xff\\xed\\x04\\x16Photoshop 3.0\\x008BIM\\x04\\x04\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\xf9\\x1c\\x02\\x05\\x00\\n103\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/azureml-envs/azureml_c1330288c44b762b0282b6f129c5292f/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/designer/serving/dagengine/processor.py\", line 18, in run\n    webservice_input, global_parameters = self.pre_process(raw_data)\n  File \"/azureml-envs/azureml_c1330288c44b762b0282b6f129c5292f/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/designer/serving/dagengine/processor.py\", line 45, in pre_process\n    json_data = json.loads(raw_data)\n  File \"/azureml-envs/azureml_c1330288c44b762b0282b6f129c5292f/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py\", line 349, in loads\n    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')\nUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte\n", "details": ""}}
```

Is anyone aware of how I should pass image data to the exposed by Azure ML endpoint?

Comment: actually the image URL I have used in GET in the example above seems to be protected by CORS, but the result does not change after using any other image URL

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the below error is because, you have not passed the input data /POST Body in the required format/schema.

To get the schema, you can either follow the schema mentioned in the error or get it from the SWAGGER.JSON file.

I prefer SWAGGER.JSON because, it gives sample usage and available endpoints. So, detailing the steps below. But if you are comfortable with constructing the POST Body with the error that is well and good.

> Note : The below is just one time process, once you get familiarized on how to consume, you will not need the below steps.

It is usually `GET https://ServiceURI.io/Swagger.json`. If you get a 404 or any error, You could check in the Deployment logs, you can find the path for the Swagger.JSON.

[image]

So in my case, it was `https://<ServiceURI.io>/swagger.json`

You can hit the above URL with GET Method you will be provided with a JSON Output.

A response like below :

[image]

Copy and JSON output and paste it in the Swagger Editor (https://editor.swagger.io/)
[You can also try reading the JSON file directly with out having it parsed in the Swagger Editor]

You will have parsed version of Swagger File and will have a quick understanding of how your endpoint must be consumed ( What are verbs and parameters that can be used with the sample)

[image]

Now expand, the **score** endpoint. That is the endpoint you will have to focus on.

You will see the sample input payload of the body  for the PUT.

```
{
  "Inputs": {
    "WebServiceInput0": [
      {
        "image": "data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA.............k=",
        "id": 134,
        "category": "dog"
      }
    ]
  },
  "GlobalParameters": {}
}
```

It might be different for you than the above.

But the main objective is send the data or (body) in the above format in addition to passing the content in bytes.

```
POST <ENDPOINT>/SCORE
HEADERS : Authorization Header
BODY : REQUIRED DATA IN the ABOVE MENTIONED FORMAT
```